# How to upload multiple files at once

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload multiple files using Dropzone.js, but it acts like it's upload one file per one upload.

For example: I select 3 files, click on the OK button, Dropzone shows OK status (successful uploaded), but server side get 3 separate request with one file per each request.

I need to get all files as an array of files, can anybody help with this case?

**Code:**

```html
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone custom_bc" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="file">
        <div class="fallback"><input type="file" name="file" multiple></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="'.$_REQUEST['object_id'].'">
        <input type="hidden" name="est_id" value="'.$_REQUEST['est_id'].'">
        <div class="dz-preview"></div>
    </form>
```

I have also tryed to put `[]` in the name of `<file>`, but it doesn't help

```html
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `uploadMultiple` to `true`.

```
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone(
            "#my-awesome-dropzone",
            {
                url: document.URL, // Set the url
                paramName: "file",
                uploadMultiple: true
            }
        );
```

When setting `uploadMultiple` to `true`, Dropzone automatucally concatenates `[]` to your file name. So you don't need to do that.